# ¿En qué países o contextos se sigue usando "vale" como despedida?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado

El Quijote tiene un prólogo que termina así:

> Y con esto, Dios te dé salud, y a mí no me olvide. VALE.

Según el diccionario, ***[vale](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bHhdVQk)*** se usa aquí con la siguiente acepción:

> Del lat. *vale* 'consérvate sano', 2.ª pers. de sing. del imper. de *valēre* 'estar sano'.
>
> 1. interj. U. alguna vez para despedirse en estilo cortesano y familiar.

Así pues, al concluir el texto con "vale" lo que está diciendo es "cuídate". Lo que me sorprende es que dicha interjección no está marcada como en desuso o poco usada. Entiendo pues que aún se sigue usando, pero ¿en qué países, regiones o contextos se sigue usando?

Comment: Desuso si recuerdo bien lo de desusado se quiere hablar de algo que lleva unos dos siglos sin uso o por ahí.  Un mero siglo no lo convertiría en desusado.  Estaba buscando la definición que utiliza ASALE en el diccionario pero no la encuentro =\

Comment: Me gusta la nueva respuesta de Colonel G.  Me parece, Charlie, que lo estás tomando demasiado literalmente con "cuídate."  Pero "para despedirse en estilo cortesano y familiar" sí va de acuerdo con la forma en que he oído "vale" al final de una conversación (por los españoles, no por los mexicanos).

Comment: En México y en España lo he oído, pero como una afirmación para manifestar que se está de acuerdo o que se comprendió lo escuchado.

Answer (score 1):

No creo que se utilice este significado de la palabra en ningún país.  Hace mucho que estudio las obras de Shakespeare o Chaucer pero seguro que ejemplos muy parecidos en esas páginas donde los personajes utilizan ciertas palabras y frases con un significado que ya no existe (por eso hay anotaciones).

El único ejemplo que se me viene a la mente es en España: si alguien está hablando con la prensa.  Dice algo como 'Esperamos que se respete el resultado de este proceso.  Vale?' y luego se marcha sin contestar más preguntas, pero es como 'Ya está', no es una despedida.

Answer (score 1):

Al menos en México, no se usa de tal manera. Quizás esa acepción que mencionas está relacionada con el uso en España de **vale** que vendría siendo un *o.k*, *de acuerdo* en México.